# Generate text blob using emacs-lisp in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to write some org-mode text (a bulleted list in this case), and then reuse it at several points in my document when exporting.

I managed to get this working by putting my text inside a source block which babel then evaluates for me, and inserting the result using `#+call:` lines. (If there is a better way to approach this problem, please let me know!)

I can get the desired result using ruby, but not using emacs-lisp, which inserts quotes and escape characters in my output.

Can anyone help me get this working with emacs-lisp? (I figured emacs-lisp is the best option since it is native to the emacs / org-mode stack, not some external interpreter that has to run, like ruby)

Below is my org mode doc with working ruby setup and failed emacs-lisp attempts, and below that is the output from export to plain text.

**This is my Org Mode doc**

```
* Testing export with ruby (is doing what I want)
#+name: generate_text_ruby
#+begin_src ruby :results output verbatim raw
puts %q{+ this is bullet 1
+ and this is bullet two}
#+end_src

This should be followed by two lines of text:
#+call: generate_text_ruby()

This should also be followed by the same two lines:
#+call: generate_text_ruby()

* Testing export with elisp (not doing what I want)
#+name: generate_text_elisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value verbatim raw
(format "+ This is bullet one,
+ and this is bullet two")
#+end_src

This should be followed by two lines of text:
#+call: generate_text_elisp()

This should also be followed by the same two lines:
#+call: generate_text_elisp()

* I also tried with print
#+name: generate_text_elisp2
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results output verbatim raw
(print "+ This is bullet one,
+ and this is bullet two")
#+end_src

This should be followed by two lines of text:
#+call: generate_text_elisp2()

This should also be followed by the same two lines:
#+call: generate_text_elisp2()
```

**This is the output from export to plain text:**

```
1 Testing export with ruby (is doing what I want)
=================================================

  ,----
  | puts %q{+ this is bullet 1
  | + and this is bullet two}
  `----

  This should be followed by two lines of text:
  + this is bullet 1
  + and this is bullet two

  This should also be followed by the same two lines:
  + this is bullet 1
  + and this is bullet two


2 Testing export with elisp (not doing what I want)
===================================================

  ,----
  | (format "+ This is bullet one,
  | + and this is bullet two")
  `----

  This should be followed by two lines of text:
  "+ This is bullet one,
  + and this is bullet two"

  This should also be followed by the same two lines:
  "+ This is bullet one,
  + and this is bullet two"


3 I also tried with print
=========================

  ,----
  | (print "+ This is bullet one,
  | + and this is bullet two")
  `----

  This should be followed by two lines of text:
  " \"+ This is bullet one,
  + and this is bullet two\"
  "

  This should also be followed by the same two lines:
  " \"+ This is bullet one,
  + and this is bullet two\"
  "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the value of the last statement, not the stdout as is returned by `:results output`. Since `:results value` is the default for Elisp blocks, you're good to go with `:results raw`.

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results raw
"+ This is bullet one,
+ and this is bullet two"
#+end_src
```

Another option that may be of interest is the following:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results list
(list "This is bullet one," "and this is bullet two")
#+end_src
```